# U2 Visual Studio 2013 Add-in

Tags: u2, u2netdk

I am in the same boat where I am not able to add add entities in the EDM file. I have downloaded the latest .NET Toolkit 1.3 from Rocketsoftware. Am I missing something, or the designer is still pending.

Please let me know as this will really make connecting to UniData a breeze.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the following steps to create Entity Data Model in Visual Studio 2013.

## Open Visual Studio 2013

[image]

## Open View->Server Explorer

[image]

## Create U2 Connection

[image]

[image]

## Create C# Winform Project

[image]

## Create ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Right click on Project and Select Add New Item.

[image]

On Right hand side, select “Data” and on left hand side select “ADO.NET Entity Data Model”. In the Name field , enter Customer. Select “Add” button

[image]

Select “EF Designer from database” and select “Next”

[image]

Select connection string and select “Yes” for sensitive data

[image]

Select Entity Framework 5.0 .
Note : v2.1.1 will include Entity Framework 6.0 functionality.

[image]

Select all tables

[image]

Press Finish and you will see Entity Data Model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ to Entity Code First Model, Visual Studio 2013 and U2 Toolkit for .NET v2.1.0.

For more information on U2 Toolkit for .NET v2.1.0, see below.

## Create Single-Value Class

```
public class CUSTOMER
{
    public int CUSTID { get; set; }
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CUSTOMER_ORDER> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

## Create Multi-Value Class

```
public class CUSTOMER_ORDER //Syntax : FILENAME_ASSOCIATION OR FILENAME_MULTIVALUE
{
    [Column (Order =0)]
    public int CUSTID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string PRODID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string SER_NUM { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int Z_MV_KEY { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    //[ForeignKey("CUSTID")]
   public virtual CUSTOMER Customer { get; set; }

}
```

## Create Relation between Single-Value Class and Multi-Value Class

```
public virtual ICollection<CUSTOMER_ORDER> Orders { get; set; }
```

public virtual CUSTOMER Customer { get; set; }

## Create Context Class

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
    {

    }
    public DbSet<CUSTOMER> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CUSTOMER_ORDER> Orders { get; set; } //Syntax : FILENAME_ASSOCIATION OR FILENAME_MULTIVALUE

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToOneConstraintIntroductionConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<AssociationInverseDiscoveryConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<DatabaseGeneratedAttributeConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<DeclaredPropertyOrderingConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<RequiredNavigationPropertyAttributeConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER>().Property(t => t.CUSTID)
                        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);


        Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER>()
        .HasKey(pk => new { pk.CUSTID })
         .ToTable("CUSTOMER");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER_ORDER>()
            .HasKey(pk => new { pk.CUSTID, pk.Z_MV_KEY })
        .ToTable("CUSTOMER_ORDER");//Syntax : FILENAME_ASSOCIATION OR FILENAME_MULTIVALUE

        modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMER_ORDER>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Customer)
        .WithMany(p => p.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.CUSTID)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    }
}
```

## Add an entry in App.Config File

```
<add name="CustomerContext" connectionString="Database=HS.SALES;User ID=user;Password=mypass;Server=myserver;Pooling=false;ServerType=universe;PersistSecurityInfo=true;AccessMode=Native;RpcServiceType=uvcs" providerName="U2.Data.Client"/>
```

## Run the App

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start...");
            Database.SetInitializer<CustomerContext>(null);
            CustomerContext ctx = new CustomerContext();
            var q = ctx.Customers.ToList();
            foreach (var item in q)
            {
                string lCUSTID = Convert.ToString(item.CUSTID);
                string lFNAME = Convert.ToString(item.FNAME); ;
                string lLNAME = Convert.ToString(item.LNAME); ;

                Console.Write("CUSTID:" + lCUSTID);
                Console.Write(" FNAME:" + lFNAME);
                Console.Write(" LNAME:" + lLNAME);

                foreach (var item2 in item.Orders)
                {
                    string lCUSTID2 = Convert.ToString(item2.CUSTID);
                    string lPRODID = Convert.ToString(item2.PRODID); ;
                    string lSER_NUM = Convert.ToString(item2.SER_NUM);
                    string lZ_MV_KEY = Convert.ToString(item2.Z_MV_KEY);

                    Console.Write("\t"+"CUSTID:" + lCUSTID2);
                    Console.Write("\t" + " PRODID:" + lPRODID);
                    Console.Write("\t" + " SER_NUM:" + lSER_NUM);
                    Console.Write("\t" + " Z_MV_KEY:" + lZ_MV_KEY);
                }


                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End...");
            Console.Read();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string lErr = e.Message;
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                lErr += e.InnerException.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(lErr);

            }
        }
    }
```

## New Features in V2.1.0

1. Complete ONE .NET Package
2. Under one roof : SQL Access, Native Access and UniObjects API
   (formerly known as UO.NET)
3. Access NoSQL (multi-value data) with SQL Syntax
4. Populate  System Builder Account Files, Attributes and Subroutines
   in Visual Studio Server Explorer.
5. Multi-value ADO.NET Provider (Native Access with U2 Files,
   Attributes, Subroutines)
6. Multi-Value Add-ins (U2 Files, Attributes, Subroutines in Visual
   Studio Server Explorer)
7. Performance Tuning Parameters in connection string:  “NativeFetch”
   and “UseFastGetRecordID”
8. Automatic Data Encryption (ADE) using U2Files and Subroutines
9. SSL using U2Files and Subroutines
10. Connection Pooling using U2Files and Subroutines
11. Drag and Drop U2Files and Subroutines into DataSet Designer and
     Entity Data Model Designer VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 Support
12. U2Files to JSON data ( to be used with JavaScript/HTML5, MVVM
     pattern/Knockout.js)
13. ASP.NET Web API and oData support using U2Files and Subroutines (
     mobile devices, Tablet App, PhoneGap Mobile App, Xamarin Mobile
     App, Windows Store)
14. ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application and Classic ASP.NET Application using
     U2Files and Subroutines
15. WCF using U2Files and Subroutines
16. WPF using U2Files and Subroutines
17. SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) using U2Files and
     Subroutines
18. SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) using U2Files and Subroutines
19. SharePoint Designer and external data sources (U2 Files and
     Subroutines)